# Multiple columns into one column without blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010. I have multiple columns with data in them, and some blank cells too. I'm using this formula:

> =INDEX($A$101:$F$200;MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$201)-1;ROWS($A$101:$F$200))+1;INT((ROW()-ROW($A$201)-1)/ROWS($A$101:$F$200))+1)

to merge them into a single long column. However, it adds there the blank cells too. Can this formula be modified to leave out those blank cells, and just merge the cells with data in them?

Example picture:

[image: example]

Comment: You could modify your formula and make it a lot more complicated, or you could do a simple 2-step process.  Do your current merge.  Then turn on a filter and hide blank rows.  Copy and paste the result.

Comment: If I can, I would like to make it automatic, meaning then I would need to make a more complicated formula. Anyone willing to help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggling, I have found something that works, though it uses two work columns (which will obviously be hidden before the sheet is used).

I tested with Excel 2007, which shows `0` instead of a blank cell when `index()` or `indirect()` returns a blank cell: I could have removed these with conditional formatting, but I have left them in so as not to obscure how the formulae are working:-

[image: Remove blank cells]

I have used your test data, so the formula copied down from `D5` is:

```
=INDEX($A$5:$B$8,MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$5),ROWS($A$5:$B$8))+1,INT((ROW()-ROW($A$5))/ROWS($A$5:$B$8))+1)
```

Column `D` is now used as a work column, and another work column `F` is created, with `F5` containing:

```
=MATCH("*",$D$5:$D$12,0)+ROW()-1
```

and copied down from `F6`:

```
=MATCH("*",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(F5+1,4,1)&":$D$12"),0)+F5
```

The significant points here are that:

- Wild-cards can be used when the third parameter of `MATCH()` is zero (unordered).
- `"*"` matches anything, but *not* the `0` returned by `INDEX()` for a blank cell.

Finally, `H5` copied down is:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("$D"&F5),"")
```

Here `IFERROR()` is used to catch the `#N/A` entries in column `F` after the last found entry.

After hiding the work columns, you get what you wanted:-

[image: Hidden work columns]

Note that, to prevent the interruption of the live column sequence, the work columns can be outside the main sheet area (eg `Y` and `Z`) or on a separate sheet, though the latter will complicate the formulae even further with sheet references.

Also, it may be possible to use only one work column, but the formulae would be of hugely increased complexity, making support very difficult.

Note also that your formulae could be regarded as unnecessarily complicated, eg `ROW($A$201)` is always 201 and `ROWS($A$101:$F$200)` is always 100; in both cases it is because absolute addressing has been used - `ROW()` and `ROWS()` become useful when cells using relative addressing are copied.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works like a charm, and it is exactly what I wanted. The extra work column doesn't bother me.